# Signal-to-Noise ration with multiple sources of noise

Tags: signals, noise

How do we calculate the signal to noise ration with multiple sources of noise signals? Do we aggregate those noise signals?

Answer (score 0):

If your signal is additive Gaussian noise, then yes.